# Simplest Turing Machine for a particular binary string

Tags: recreational-mathematics, turing-machines

At the [Bank of England](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/news/2019/july/50-pound-banknote-character-announcement) is a proposed £50 note.

[image]

Alan Turing was born on the 23rd June 1912. 23061912 in decimal is 1010111111110010110011000.

Starting from a blank tape, what is the simplest Turing machine that generates 1010111111110010110011000 at some stage?

Starting from a blank tape, what is the simplest Turing machine that generates 1010111111110010110011000 and halts?

Comment: A simple upper bound would be the brute force method, which would have 22 instructions: (A, R0, W1, B), (B, R0, W0, C)... (U, R0, W1, V), (V, R0, W1, HALT), where an instruction is (Start State, Read Bit, Write Bit, Next State).

Comment: How are you measuring simplicity? Or is there an implicit "without using more symbols than blank, 0, 1"?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer to the first question is a 3-state machine:

[image]

This machine starts with a blank tape and creates every binary number (and never terminates).

The second question is a tough one. I have a feeling that it is possible to do in $\approx 8-10$ states, but I am still figuring this out.